# Printing hashmap instances ordered using priority queue

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable, priority-queue

I have inserted the distinct words of a txt file and how many times they repeat in a hashmap as keys and values respectively. The thing is, I want to print the k most used words in descending order using a PQ, but although it seems easy to insert the values in the priority queue of integers and then get the k max integers, I can't figure out a way to get the key corresponding to each value back again to print it (the values might not be unique). A solution would be to invert the hashmap, but it doesn't seem as a "safe" choice.

```
public static void main(int k)throws IOException{

   //Create input stream & scanner
   FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("readwords.txt");
   Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(file);

   Map<String, Integer> frequency = new HashMap<>();
   LinkedList<String> distinctWords = new LinkedList<String>();
   PriorityQueue<Integer> pQueue = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();

   //Read through file and find the words
   while(fileInput.hasNext()){
       //Get the next word
       String nextWord = fileInput.next().toLowerCase();
       //Determine if the word is in the HashMap
       if(frequency.containsKey(nextWord)) {
           frequency.put(nextWord, frequency.get(nextWord) + 1);
       }
       else {
            frequency.put(nextWord, 1);
            distinctWords.add(nextWord);
       }


    }

    //Close
    fileInput.close();
    file.close();



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be multiple solution, here is mine. create a `class` with two fields; one for the `String` and one for the `Integer`. Make the class implement `Comparable` and override the method `compareTo` so it compares the `Integers`.

```
public class WordFrequency implements Comparable<WordFrequency> {
    private String word;
    private Integer frequency;

    public WordFrequency(String word, Integer frequency) {
        this.word = word;
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }

    // descending order
    @Override
    public int compareTo(WordFrequency o) {
        return o.getFrequency() - this.getFrequency();
    }

    public Integer getFrequency() {
        return this.frequency;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return word + ": " + frequency;
    }
}
```

Then, convert your `map<String, Integer>` to a `PriorityQueue<WordFrequency>`:

```
PriorityQueue<WordFrequency> pQueue = frequency.entrySet().stream()
        .map(m -> new WordFrequency(m.getKey(), m.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(PriorityQueue::new));
```

If you want to print it, you must use `poll()`, otherwise the order is not guaranteed.

```
while(!pQueue.isEmpty())
        System.out.println(pQueue.poll());
```